# Erlang App don't make project

Tags: linux, erlang, linux-mint, rebar

There is a project in the language of Erlang, if I want to raise it with Rebar, Rebar that is get-deps + rebar compile I get an error like this:

```
 Uncaught error in rebar_core: {'EXIT',
                           {badarg,
                            [{io,format,
                              [standard_io,
                               "WARN:  Expected ~s to be an app dir (containing                ebin/*.app), but no .app found.\n",
                               [[47,104,111,109,101,47,117,115,101,114,47,
                                 1044,1086,1082,1091,1084,1077,1085,1090,
                                 1099,47,80,114,111,106,101,99,116,47,99,
                                 111,110,118,95,112,108,117,103,105,110,
                                 115,47,100,101,112,115,47,112,111,111,
                                 108,98,111,121]]],
                              []},
                             {rebar_deps,is_app_available,5,
                              [{file,"src/rebar_deps.erl"},{line,460}]},
                             {rebar_deps,find_dep_in_dir,3,
                              [{file,"src/rebar_deps.erl"},{line,403}]},
                             {rebar_deps,find_deps,4,
                              [{file,"src/rebar_deps.erl"},{line,368}]},
                             {rebar_deps,preprocess,2,
                              [{file,"src/rebar_deps.erl"},{line,64}]},
                             {rebar_core,acc_modules,5,
                              [{file,"src/rebar_core.erl"},{line,537}]},
                             {rebar_core,process_dir1,7,
                              [{file,"src/rebar_core.erl"},{line,234}]},
                             {rebar_core,process_commands,2,
                              [{file,"src/rebar_core.erl"},{line,90}]}]}}
 make: *** [get-deps] Error 1
```

I have reinstalled the operating system Linux Mint 17.1 and than install Ubuntu 14.04 + OTP Erlang 17.0 from erlang_solutions + rebar from github.

1. step1 - I install Erlang .deb file + Install pаckage
2. step2 - I clone Rebar from github and in directory of rebar use
   command - ./bootstrap than I create in bin new folder vs rebar
3. step3 I clone project from Git and in project directory make
   command  rebar get-deps and rebar compile, and than I had problem :(

My friend on Mac OS and Ubuntu compile this project and didn't have this problem. They use OTP Erlang 17.0 and Rebar from github. Plis, help! What am I doing wrong?

Comment: plz give us more details like your code or minimal example that reproduce the problem.

Comment: looks like rebar is choking on a path with unicode chars? what is the full pathname of the directory containing your project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 problems here. The path to the app directory contains unicode chars so the error message cannot be displayed by rebar. But it seems that the root cause of the problem is that rebar is looking for an app file (application.app) in the directory (the one with unicode name) and it can't find any.
Even if rebar does not complain about finding the directory, it may be also a possible cause of the problem.

Comment: path where my project has the following form user/Документы/Project/MyProject Maybe the problem is to place the project in this way?